# $.get and saving global variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, anonymous-function

```
var a = 0;
var requestStr ="https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.interestingness.getList&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&per_page=20&api_key=dc140afe3fd3a251c2fdf9dcd835be5c"; //flickr key.
$.get(requestStr, function(data){
    a = data;
});

console.log(a);
```

This prints out 0, but im trying to save the `data` parameter into the global variable `a.`

I've tried a self invoking function and using a 2nd function to set `a = data`, but they don't work.

Honestly can't figure this out.

Comment: Whatever you want to do with your `data` should be done after the `$.get()` callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have promise:

```
$.get(requestStr, function(data){
    a = data;
}).always(function(){
    console.log(a);
});
```

Because `$.get()` method is async call, so the response take time to come and the execution of js codes gets executed.

Other than this you might want to take a look at `$.when()`.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax calls are asynchronous, which means `a = data;` gets called after `console.log(a);`, because fetching data from web takes time.

You need to process data when the data actually arrives:

```
var a = 0;
var requestStr ="https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.interestingness.getList&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&per_page=20&api_key=dc140afe3fd3a251c2fdf9dcd835be5c"; //flickr key.
$.get(requestStr, function(data){
    a = data;
    console.log(a);
});
```